# Apache web server mod_rewrite module RewriteRule problem

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, tomcat6

I have a Struts 2 application on Tomcat 6. There is a Apache 2.2 web server in front of Tomcat.
I am trying to create Google friendly URLs by mod_rewrite.

What I am trying to do:
When I request `http://domainname/some-title`, 
it must reach to Tomcat as `http://domainname:8080/fetch.action?entry.title=some-title`

I wrote a rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  /fetch.action?entry.title=$1    [L]
```

But it doesnt work!
Does anyone help me? Thanks.

My Apache virtual host configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ihlsozluk
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule     ^/(.*)  /fetch.action?entry.title=$1    [L]
    JkMount /* worker1
    ErrorLog logs/ihlsozluk-error.log
    CustomLog logs/ihlsozluk-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an internal proxy request as the destination port 8080 is probably only internally reachable:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/fetch.action?entry.title=$1 [L,P]
```